# Azure self-hosted pipeline problem for deploying Container app

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, containers

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\\pwsh.exe" -command "CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name mystudio --output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken'); docker login mystudio.azurecr.io -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p $CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN > /dev/null 2>&1"
CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name mystudio--output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken'): The term 'CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name mystudio --output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken')' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Out-File: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\dev\null'.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: PwshCommandFailed
##[error]PwshCommandFailed CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az acr login --name mystudio --output json --expose-token --only-show-errors | jq -r '.accessToken'); docker login mystudio .azurecr.io -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p $CA_ADO_TASK_ACR_ACCESS_TOKEN > /dev/null 2>&1
##[error]Unable to authenticate against ACR instance 'mystudio.azurecr.io' with access token.
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\\pwsh.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

I think there is at least 2 problems here, 1 of them is that the command not been recognized, and another is this is self-hosted windows agent pool, the `> /dev/null 2>&1` seems not quite right..